# how to create jar file when I have multiple classes in a package( in netbeans )

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have multiple classes like `Index.java`, `Login.java`, `Create.java`, `Update.java` in my package. I have tried to make jar file with netbeans this way

> Run -> Clean and Build Project

It generates a jar but when  I run it, then it starts with Index.java but I  want the project start with `Login.java`

Comment: Right click on project  , properties->Run->Main class , change it to your Login.java

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on project ,

> **properties->Run->Main class**

change it's value to your Login.java , then clean and build again.

[image: Netbeans]

*this screenshot is from netbeans 8.0.2*

Answer (score 0):

try [Oracle Docs Step 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) or  [Oracle Docs Step 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step2.html)